# Why can't I open my MiKTeX console?

Tags: miktex

[image]

What does

> the parameter is incorrect

mean?

Comment: Close the console and make sure that no other TeX-related programmes and processed are running (check with the task manager: You'll want to look for `pdflatex`, `latex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`, `miktex-...`, `texworks`, ...). You could re-start your PC to be absolutely sure. Then try again.